# What does indexPath.row return?

Tags: objective-c, tableview, rows, cells

i am reading the Big Nerd Ranch guide on Objective c programming and i have the code:

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.tasks count]; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // Get a reusable cell
    UITableViewCell *c = [self.taskTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    // This below is what i don't understand
    NSString *item = [self.tasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    c.textLabel.text = item;

    return c;
}
```

I don't understand what indexPath.row returns or what index it is representing in the array, i have just reach the part of the book where i actually get to make small applications, so i am used to just passing an integer for an index.

> NSString *item = [self.tasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

I don't know if all this code is needed but i just wanted to make sure you had all the code needed to answer the question.

.h file -
http://pastebin.com/TRnPqn4d

.m file - 
http://pastebin.com/YXZffwye

Answer (score 7):

The `indexPath` you are relating to here includes two bits of information.

1. The `section` - The section in the table that the cell is going to be placed into.
2. The `row` - The row (in the section) that the cell will be placed into.

So to answer "What does it return?". It depends on which section/row the cell is going to go into.

The function it is in is run once for each visible row. So to start with the `indexPath.row` will be 0. Then it will be 1, then 2, then 3 and so on.

You do this so that you can get the correct string from the array each time.

Comment: There is only 1 section, but how does indexPath.row know anything about my array?

Comment: @hanseN it doesn't. Your array contains some number of values. You then tell it this in the `numberOfRows` method (`return array.count`). So the table creates that many rows. You get stuff from an array with a number `array[0]` ... `array[1]` etc... the `indexPath.row` just creates these numbers.

Comment: So indexPath.row will increment by one for each object i add to the array?

Comment: @hanseN no, well yes but... You are placing too much dependancy between the `array` and the `indexPath`. Your array of strings (`self.tasks`) represents the rows of the table. When you load (or reload) the table using `[self.table reloadData];` then the table first asks "How many rows should I have?" You then tell it this. Then the table says "Right, what goes into row 0?". "OK, now what goes into row 1?", "Now, row 2?", "And 3?", etc... until it gets to the correct number of rows you told it. So each time it asks it passes in a new `indexPath` to represent the `row` and the `section`.

Comment: What you are doing in code is saying. The cell that goes into row 0. Well, thats going to display the string from my `tasks` array at index 0.

Comment: So if i store 1 string object in my array then in the cellForRow method i will create a reusable cell and then in *item store the string object at the index equal to the row number so if there is no rows yet the indexPath.row will be row number 0? or am i completely off?

Comment: @hanseN yeah that's correct. Except for the first object the row number is 0. If there are no objects then this method is never called at all. Also, item is only "stored" for a very short time. Just long enough to get it and put it into the label.

Comment: But when i print *item using NSLog() it will print all string objects created every time, why is that?

Comment: Yes. It prints it out once for each row. First it prints out the first one. Then the second one. Then the third one. Because that function is run multiple times. Once for each row.

Comment: so when one row is added this,  method will be run for this row and giving it the string equal to index 0 in the array, (which is the row number?)  when another row is added it will first run this method (cellForRowAtIndexPath:) on first row and THEN on the new row?

Comment: and does tableviews not have built in rows i just couldnt see them i wasnt using any separatorstyle

Comment: @hanseN yes. That. Also, no. You put the rows into table views using the method we are talking about.

Comment: @hanseN I'm not really sure where the confusion is here. You have a function that is run multiple times and a parameter that is passed into it. You seem to be getting caught up in rows and row numbers etc... I've tried to answer your questions but you seem to be over complicating it a lot. It isn't as complex as you're thinking.

Comment: I think the confusion is what indexPath.row is returning everytime it gets called

Comment: @hanseN this is where I don't understand the confusion. A table has rows. The index path row is just the row of the table. So, for the first row it will be 0. Then for the second row it will be 1. And so on. You can find this easily by putting the `indexPath.row` into the text label on the cell. I understand the question. Just not the confusion. It is literally just a number. 0 1 2 3 4 5...

Comment: Yeah but only 1 row is told to be added at a time by rowsInSection: and that is everytime i press a button i don't how or when that row is added or when this method is executed. is it when table is reloaded is addTask: it seems very confusing to me

Comment: Ok. I think the confusion is that you are thinking of adding rows. You are not adding rows. You are adding items to your array. Then when you call `reloadData` on the table it will manage the cells that represent the data.

Comment: Doesn't it get a string from tasks array? at a certain index? and it's that index i dont understand. I know NSIndexPath is is a node to a nested array collections, but it's that instance of NSIndexPath's property row i don't know what index it represents each time, and what index in array it gets the string?

Comment: What exactly about that index don't you understand. And yes, you're right. The first string in the array is at index 0 and goes into the first row. The second string in the array is at index 1 and goes into the second row.

Comment: Yes but what number exactly? If i have 4 items in array? And it gets called for fifth time?

Comment: The row number. For row 0 it is 0. For row 1 it is 1. That function is run multiple times. Once for each of the rows that you have told it that the table has. If you tell it the table has three rows then it will run this function with 0, 1, 2. If you tell it it has 5 rows then it will run it with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. And so on.

Comment: If you have 4 items in your array then it won't get called a fifth time because you have already told it there are 4 rows (the method `numberOfRows...` is returning the size of the array).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69746/discussion-on-answer-by-fogmeister-what-does-indexpath-row-return).

Comment: so if numberOfRows is returning 4 (adding 1 row at a time) rows it will get called for each row, and each row has a number and the index will be equal to that number?

Comment: Yes. Thats correct. I'm really not sure what I can say now to make this any different. Hope you understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

NSIndexPath UIKit Additions adds  a category on `NSIndexPath` that adds `section` and `row` properties along with a few other additions.

`row`
An index number identifying a row in a section of a table view. (read-only)
`@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger row`

`section`
An index number identifying a section in a table view or collection view. (read-only)
`@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger section`